# How can I glue() a ZeroClipboard clip to a newly inserted element?

Tags: jquery, flash, copy-paste, zeroclipboard

I am trying to write a basic blogging platform, and I want to offer users the ability to copy code within a pre block to their clipboard.

I am using [ZeroClipboard](https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard/) to achieve this. Once the document is ready, I loop through each `pre` on the page, adding a clipboard item to it as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath( 'ZeroClipboard/ZeroClipboard.swf' );
        var preNum = 1

        $('pre').each(function() {
            // Get a unique id for the element I will be inserting
            var id = 'copy-btn-' + preNum++
            // Capture the text to be copied to the clipboard
            var text = $(this).text()
            // Insert the element, just before this
            $('<div class="copy-btn" id="' + id + '-cont"><i class="icon-file icon-white" id="' + id + '"></i></div>').insertBefore(this)
            // Capture the newly inserted element
            var elem = $(this).prev()

            // Create the clip, and glue it to the element
            var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
            clip.setText(text)
            clip.glue(elem)
       })
   });
```

When I try to do this, the javascript console reports: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'zIndex' of undefined`

My current understanding of the problem is that the inserted element is not yet available in the dom when I try to glue the clip to it, which is why no gluing is occurring.

Anybody know how I might be able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Gluing instructions](https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard/blob/master/docs/instructions.md#gluing):

> You can pass in a DOM element ID (as shown above), or a reference to
>   the actual DOM element object itself.

Your code doesn't work because you're passing a jQuery object to it.

You can pass the ID:

```
clip.glue(id + '-cont')
```

Or an actual DOM element reference:

```
clip.glue(elem[0])
```

The above example uses the shorthand for the [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) jQuery object method.